Активна / пасивна здатність -ливий / -кний
Цікавить, чому така розбіжність -- в одних словах -ливий це пасив і -кний це актив, а в інших навпаки. Чому так, просто історично склалось?



неозначена ф.
актив/пасив
пасив/актив




стискати
стискний
стисливий


проникати
проникний
прони-к-ливий



Активна здатність

стискний Те саме, що стискальний.
Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005.


стисний Який викликає стискання речовини, зменшення її об'єму, ущільнення.
Тлумачний словник української мови в 11-ти томах


проникливий

Який глибоко розуміє суть чого-небудь, правильно оцінює когось, щось, розбирається в чомусь.
Який виражає які-небудь почуття, настрої і т. ін.
Пильний, спостережливий, гострий (про очі, погляд і т. ін.).
Який проникає куди-небудь.

Тлумачний словник української мови в 11-ти томах

Брикливий, верескливий, вискливий, матюкливий.
Пасивна здатність

стисливий Здатний стискатися, зменшуватися в об'ємі, ущільнюватися під дією зовнішнього тиску.
Тлумачний словник української мови в 11-ти томах


проникний здатний пропускати крізь себе що-небудь.
Тлумачний словник української мови в 11-ти томах

Лякливий

Все ж таки, мені здається, що слова на -ливий частіше показують активну здатність.
